# Why am I getting the wrong average in C?

Tags: c

I'm new at this and having some trouble. I'm trying to find the average of the grades that are inputed by the user but I realized that if you use a decimal in any of the grades, it's just being calculated as if they are whole numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned int counter;
    float grade;
    int total;
    float average;
    int number;
    
    total = 0;
    counter = 1;
    
    printf("Number of scores to enter:\t");
    scanf("%d", &number);

    printf("\n");
    
    while (counter <= number) {
        printf("%s%d%s", "Enter the score for Lab ", counter, ":\t");
        scanf("%f", &grade);
        total = total + grade;
        counter = counter + 1;
    }
    
    printf("\n");
    
    average = (float) total / number;
    
    printf("Average lab score: %.1f\n", average);
    
    if (grade>=90) {
        puts("Letter grade: A");
    }
    else if (grade>=80) {
        puts("Letter grade: B");
    }
    else if (grade>=70) {
        puts("Letter grade: C");
    }
    else if (grade>=60) {
        puts("Letter grade: D");
    }
    else {
        puts("Letter grade: F");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `total` is an `int`, so your floating point values get rounded during tabulation. Needing to do `(float) total` is a hint something's wrong.

Comment: You are accumulating grades into variable `total`, which has type `int`.  At each assignment to that variable, any fractional part is dropped.

Comment: `total` is not rounded, but truncated.  Not quite the same.  But still not what you want.

Comment: The part where you convert to letter grades is using the last grade entered, rather than the average.

Comment: The `grade` in `if`s is the score of the *last* lab.

Comment: @tadman Incorrect.  No rounding is performed.  The values are simply truncated when added to an integer.  For example, `int x = 0 + 1.99;` sets `x` to `1`, and not `2` as you imply.

Comment: @TomKarzes Truncation is a form of rounding: Rounding down to nearest integer. There are *many* ways to round, that's just one.

Comment: @tadman In a broad sense, that's true.  In a specific sense, people almost always mean some form of rounding to the nearest integer.  Using the term "rounding" when truncation is intended is misleading.  In fact, C has a `round` function that rounds to the nearest integer.

Comment: @tadman: even that isn’t correct, because negative numbers get rounded *up*.  It’s less inaccurate to say “rounds towards zero”, but it’s still inaccurate.  Any fractional portion is simply discarded.

Comment: @TomKarzes The level of pedantry is far too high for what is intended to be a simple explanation without diving deep into the merits of different rounding methods. If anyone wants a deeper explanation they can ask for one.

Answer (score 1):

You are capturing `scanf("%f", &grade);` as a float and then calculating `total = total + grade;`.

You have defined `int total;`. You would need to define it as `float total;`.

You are moving a float variable into an integer which is truncating the decimals you had previously entered.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to ask up front how many data points will be entered.  Indeed, that is an anti-pattern.  Just do something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(void)
{
        unsigned int count = 0;
        float grade;
        float total = 0.0;
        float average;

        while( scanf("%f", &grade) == 1 ) {
                total += grade;
                count += 1;
        }
        average = total / (float) count;
        printf("Average lab score: %.1f\n", average);
        fputs("Letter grade: ", stdout);
        putchar( average >= 90.0 ? 'A' : average >= 80.0 ? 'B' :
                average >= 70.0 ? 'C' : average >= 60.0 ? 'D' : 'F');
        putchar('\n');

        return average >= 60.0;
}

$ echo 78.2 96.5 80 | ./a.out
Average lab score: 84.9
Letter grade: B
```

Key points: `total` needs to be a float type.  You *must* check the value returned by `scanf`.  Always.  Probably you want to handle bad input more cleanly that this does.  This just throws away all data after an error and computes the average based on whatever data was entered prior to the error.  A cleaner solution would abort with an error message.  Exercise left for the reader.

A reasonable argument can be made that this is an abuse of the ternary operator; however you want to refactor it, don't repeat yourself by hardcoding the string "Letter grade: " multiple times.

Rather than abusing the ternary operator as above, you may prefer something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(void)
{
        unsigned int count = 0;
        float grade;
        float total = 0.0;
        float average;

        while( scanf("%f", &grade) == 1 ) {
                total += grade;
                count += 1;
        }
        average = total / (float) count;
        int s = 'A' + (99 - (int)average) / 10;
        printf("Average lab score: %.1f\n", average);
        printf("Letter grade: %c\n", s > 'D' ? 'F' : s);

        return average >= 60.0;
}
```